# ARR is stripping custom headers from my pages

Tags: iis, arr

We're using the ARR extension to IIS to rewrite requests to a website running a different app pool using the server farm feature.

I want to be able to set a custom header on the response when I generate my page inside the server farm, but it's getting stripped out as it comes through ARR.

I tried using the `<serverVariables>` functionality, but that only lets you add headers from the ARR routing website into the request as it goes into the website with the pages, not the other way around.

Comment: Are you sure, that ARR strips it? Did you bypass ARR to verify the headers?

Comment: Yep, when I access the page directly I get the header. When I go via ARR it disappears.